# Error after following official Homebrew installation instructions

Tags: installation, homebrew, traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:31:in `<main>'

    2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:31:in `require_relative'

    1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:8:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
```

Comment: Remove it and reinstall again

Comment: i had done for several times but result still the same